# From where does it come from, that the head and feet considered an enemy?

Tags: genesis, revelation, new-testament, daniel, eden

In the book of Genesis, it is said that he will crush your head and you will strike his heel and the creator will put enmity between her seed and his seed. Are the head and feet meant for an enemy in the kingdom of heaven? From where does it come from? Even in the book of Daniel the statue of the image of a man with the head of gold and his feet of clays and iron, a rock came and struck his feet and the image of the idol was scattered by the wind to the 4th corners of the world.
Jesus too washed the feet of his disciples.

> Gen 3:15 - And I will put enmity between you and the woman,
>
> and between your seed and her seed.
>
> He will crush your head,
>
> and you will strike his heel.”

Comment: Christ being ascended on high, in humanity, (above the realm of the serpentine spirit) bruises, from above, the head of the serpent, is the interpretation usually expressed in regard to this passage.

Answer (score 3):

Long before the Bible record started to be written, humanity as a whole thought of the head as signifying knowledge, and the feet as menial parts of the body that had contact with the dust of the ground. I doubt if the origin (i.e. earliest records) of that could be pinpointed. The Bible simply uses the head, and the feet, to signify many spiritual truths, or points, and Genesis chapter 3 is the first instance of that.

However, an accurate quotation of the verse in question needs to be fully given and its translation reference also added. Like this:

God is speaking to the serpent in Eden, and says:

> "Because thou hast done this, thou art cursed above all cattle, and
> above every beast of the field; upon thy belly shalt thou go, and dust
> thou shalt eat all the days of thy life. And I will put enmity between
> thee and the woman, and between thy seed and her seed; it shall bruise
> thy head, and thou shalt bruise his heel." Genesis 3:14-15 A.V.

The text is not speaking about the Kingdom of Heaven. It is giving a prophecy about future events. It is stating a curse upon the devil, who appeared as a serpent to the woman (who had not yet been named 'Eve'). It speaks of dust of the earth, of a serpentine 'seed' and a 'seed' of the woman. It speaks of on-going enmity between those two opposing 'seeds', resulting in the serpent's head being bruised, and the serpent bruising the heel of the other. The Hebrew word for 'to bruise' is *'shuph'* in both cases.

Please note that ***the feet are not mentioned. One heel is mentioned***. It gets bruised, but the one doing that has his head bruised.

Given what was stated in earlier verses, there is significance in the role of dust of the ground, and knowledge. The serpent claimed that the couple disobeying God would come to know how to be 'as God', whereas God had warned that that way would lead to death (which it did). The serpent offered the fruit of the tree of the ***knowledge*** of good and evil - obtaining knowledge to elevate themselves. In reality, it brought them down to the ground - to the grave. And the serpent had to then crawl on its belly, in the dust of the ground, 'eating dust'.

Trampling with the feet is, however, a common theme in the Bible, from treading grapes to destroying enemies, as is that of crowns being placed on the heads of kings. God will trample all his enemies, but give crowns to his children who will reign with Christ in heavenly glory. That, however, is not in the text of the Bible's first prophecy. The only sense of the head 'being an enemy' as you put it, is the symbolism of the devil's head being bruised. So much for the head-knowledge the serpentine seed continues to offer humanity to get them away from knowing the Christ of God! That will be crushed, whereas when Christ's symbolic 'heel' was bruised at the cross, that had no lasting effect.

Comment: 'Long before the bible record . . . . . . ' I would say that records were kept, from the beginnings of humanity. And I would say that 'humanity as a whole' were (originally) influenced by the events and words recorded in Genesis. That Moses, eventually, put all that into the public domain does not mean that the influences were not already there prior to that publication.

Comment: Everyone follows seven days, I don't know where it came from other than the book of the five books of Moses.

Comment: The ancient and honourable, he is the head; and the prophet that teacheth lies, he is the tail (Isa. 9:15 KJV)

Comment: Good answer. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Genesis 3:14-15 NIV

> 14 So the Lord God said to the serpent, “Because you have done this,
> “Cursed are you above all livestock
> and all wild animals!
> **You will crawl on your belly**
> and you will eat dust
> all the days of your life.
>
> 15 And I will put enmity
> between you and the woman,
> and between your offspring and hers;
> he will crush your **head**,
> and you will strike his **heel**.”

This script describes the conflict between the sons of God and the sons of the devil, alternatively between Jesus and Satan. But I think it is applicable to the conflict in our mind, the desire to be holy and the desire of the world.

Just that I don't find any spiritual meaning regarding the use of 'head' and 'heel' (feet) in here. A literal understanding is when the serpent crawls on its belly and attacks a human, naturally the human will try to use his feet to crush the serpent head, and the serpent attacks his feet for it is the height it can get.

I think the focal point of this metaphor is about the conflict between good and evil, but not the images that used to describe it.